# How to solve the following SDEs?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the SDEs

$dx_t = x_t \log x_t\text{d}t + x_t\text{d}W_t$

$dx_t = x_t^2 \text{d}t + x_t\text{d}W_t$

How do you solve something like these? I tried $x_t=F(W_t,t)$, but could not get a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first equation, note that
\begin{align*}
d\ln x_t = (\ln x_t -\frac{1}{2}) dt + dW_t,
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
d\left(e^{-t}\ln x_t \right) &=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}dt + e^{-t} dW_t.
\end{align*}
Then $x_t$ can be expressed as an integral form.

Comment: How do you know what are the right functions to try? That is perhaps what I am asking.

Comment: As there is a log function in the equation, try the derivative for the logarithm is the natural choice. Moreover, it is a popular technique to use integral factor for such type of equations.

Comment: would you be able to provide a reference for this? What do you call it, integral factor for solving SDE?